# Cronjob function is not executed

Tags: module, magento-1, cron

I have created a custom module and set a cronjob, like this:

**Mymodule/Sales/etc/config.xml**

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <mymodule_sales_synch_orders>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>s1sales/schedule::synchOrders</model>
            </run>
        </mymodule_sales_synch_orders>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

In **Mymodule/Sales/Model/Schedule.php:**

```
class Mymodule_Sales_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function synchOrders(){
        Mage::log('synchOrders() start', null, 'Mymodule.log');
        if (Mage::helper('s1sales')->isSynchEnabled()){
            Mage::getModel('s1sales/order_synch')->synchOrders();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Seems out that **synchOrders()** function is never executed. 
I'm struggling to find a solution but can't see what's wrong with this. Any ideas?

*I have checked that log is enabled and Mymodule.log file is writable, in case someone asks.

Comment: Please add your whole `config.xml ` as I highly doubt that the definition `<run><model>s1sales/schedule::synchOrders</model></run>` is correct (or just try `<run><model>Mymodule_Sales_Model_Observer::synchOrders</model></run>` instead). Also, it does not seem to be meaningful to have a cron-executed method inside an observer class (in my opinion it would be better to put it into a separate class)...

Comment: Sec...`Mymodule/Sales/Model/Schedule.php` holds a class named `Mymodule_Sales_Model_Observer` ? Is this your actual code? The class in `Mymodule/Sales/Model/Schedule.php` mus be called `Mymodule_Sales_Model_Schedule`

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice about Mymodule_Sales_Model_Observer. Changed it to Mymodule_Sales_Model_Schedule and it's working ok now. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Certainly... ;)

Comment: Download the magerun(https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) and execute this: `./n98-magerun sys:cron:run mymodule_sales_synch_orders` and see the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments already there is either an issue in your model-definition or in your file name structure.

According to your snippets `Mymodule/Sales/Model/Schedule.php` holds a class named `Mymodule_Sales_Model_Observer`. However, the class in `Mymodule/Sales/Model/Schedule.php` must be called `Mymodule_Sales_Model_Schedule` (or the file's name and the model-alias in your `<run><model>` node in `config.xml` must be changed to `Observer.php` and `s1sales/observer::synchOrders`) since otherwise the autoloader wont be able to process your class accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a mistake In your `model` section please try this config.

```
 <model>s1sales/observer::synchOrders</model>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set Magento  main cron job. I think you might not set it. Because extension cron will be scheduled by main Magento cron.

Comment: Magento main cronjob is running. And my custom cronjob "mymodule_sales_synch_orders" is scheduled and running normaly. It's just doing nothing.